# Processing multi line logs with AWK to gather SQL statements

Tags: bash, awk

I have the following entries in a log file:

```
2016-01-25 21:12:41 UTC:172.31.21.125(56665):user@production:[21439]:ERROR:  bind message supplies 1 parameters, but
prepared statement "" requires 0

2016-01-25 21:12:41 UTC:172.31.21.125(56665):user@production:[21439]:STATEMENT:  SELECT count(*) AS total FROM (
                SELECT 1 AS count
                  FROM leads_search_criteria_entities
                  INNER JOIN entities e on entity_id = e.viq_id
                  LEFT JOIN companies_user cu ON cu.entity_id = e.viq_id
                  WHERE criterium_id = 644 AND ((
                ( cu.udef_type IS NULL -- if not set by user, check calculated value
                  AND is_university >= 50
                ) OR (
                  cu.udef_type IS NOT NULL -- if set by user, use it
                  AND cu.udef_type = 'university'
                )
              ))
                  GROUP BY e.viq_id

                  ORDER BY e.viq_id
                ) x
2016-01-25 21:14:11 UTC::@:[2782]:LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
2016-01-25 21:14:16 UTC::@:[2782]:LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 51 buffers (0.0%); 0 transaction log file(s) added, 0 remov
ed, 0 recycled; write=5.046 s, sync=0.038 s, total=5.091 s; sync files=18, longest=0.008 s, average=0.002 s
2016-01-25 21:19:11 UTC::@:[2782]:LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
```

I would like to capture the SQL statements but I am not sure how can I do that with AWK.

Update:

Expected outcome:

```
SELECT count(*) AS total FROM ( SELECT 1 AS count FROM leads_search_criteria_entities INNER JOIN entities e on entity_id = e.viq_id LEFT JOIN companies_user cu ON cu.entity_id = e.viq_id WHERE criterium_id = 644 AND (( ( cu.udef_type IS NULL -- if not set by user, check calculated value AND is_university >= 50 ) OR ( cu.udef_type IS NOT NULL -- if set by user, use it AND cu.udef_type = 'university' ) )) GROUP BY e.viq_id ORDER BY e.viq_id ) x
```

My current almost working solution uses sed but this is where I got stuck, it just helps filtering the lines that have a select (multiple lines by itself) and the next line after that. Any suggestion is appreciated

```
sed -n "/:STATEMENT:/,/2016/p" out
```

Comment: What would like to do with them? Just dump onto the stdout? Do you have any code to begin with? What is an SQL statement (e.g. the start of it can be any line having `:STATEMENT:`)?

Comment: Please post expected outcome for us not fluently in SQL.

Comment: I have added the expected outcome to the question. Thank you.

Comment: @Istvan, please try to write something, rather than just describing the problem and asking for someone to write something for you. StackOverflow is valuable not because you can get free programming service here, but because it helps you get through your own programming challenges. Post your attempt, explain why you think it should work, show us your results whether they're an error or unexpected output. And we'll help you fix your code. I'm voting to close this question, but I'll retract the close vote if you [update your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend using sed for this.  First thought for an awk solution might look like this:

```
/^2016/&&line~/:STATEMENT:/ {
  sub(/.*:STATEMENT:/,"",line)
  print line
}
/^2016/ {
  line=""
}
{
  $1=$1
  line=sprintf("%s %s",line,$0)
}
END {
  if (line~/:STATEMENT:/) {
    sub(/.*:STATEMENT:/,"",line)
    print line
  }
}
```

Obviously you could shrink this. I wrote and ran it (for testing) as a one-liner.

The idea here is that:

- we'll append to a variable, resetting it every time our input line starts with the year. (You could replace this with a regexp matching the date if you want to run this next year without modification),
- when we get to a new log line (or the end), we strip off the cruft before the SQL statement and print the result.

Note the `$1=$1`. The purpose of this is to change your line's whitespace, so that newlines and tabs and multiples spaces are collapsed into single spaces. Experiment with removing it to see the impact.

Comment: Thanks for the solution & for the explanation as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat log.awk
f && /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/ {f=0; print ""}
sub(/^.*:STATEMENT:[[:space:]]+/,"") {f=1}
f { $1=$1; printf "%s ", $0 }

$ awk -f log.awk log.txt
SELECT count(*) AS total FROM ( SELECT 1 AS count FROM leads_search_criteria_entities INNER JOIN entities e on entity_id = e.viq_id LEFT JOIN companies_user cu ON cu.entity_id = e.viq_id WHERE criterium_id = 644 AND (( ( cu.udef_type IS NULL -- if not set by user, check calculated value AND is_university >= 50 ) OR ( cu.udef_type IS NOT NULL -- if set by user, use it AND cu.udef_type = 'university' ) )) GROUP BY e.viq_id ORDER BY e.viq_id ) x
```

(2nd line) This turns on printing (`f=1`) when `:STATEMENT:` is found, and as a side-effect, removes everything up until the start of the SELECT statement.

(3rd line) Then it keeps printing until printing is turned off (see below), cleaning up by replacing sequences of multiple spaces by a single space. (**EDIT**: Thanks to @ghoti for suggesting the elegant `$1=$1` for that.)

(1st line) Turn off printing at the start of the next log, identified by starting with a date. Print a courtesy newline to end the SELECT.

Comment: This answer is not portable because of the use of `gsub()`. Per my answer, you can eliminate your `gsub()` simply with `$1=$1`, making this answer portable with POSIX awk rather than depending on GNU awk.

Comment: @ghoti, `gsub()` is not limited to GNU awk and should be portable, but in any case I like your idea of using `$1=$1` very much and will improve my answer accordingly!

Comment: Thank you very much for posting this, I like your approach too!

Comment: @jas - ah, right you are, I should know better than to comment before coffee. And .. glad I could help. :)

Comment: Now that I've had coffee, I realize that collapsing whitespace with `$1=$1` has the potential to affect content *within quoted elements of the SQL statement*, not just the initial whitespace on the line. If it isn't important to be able to accurately reproduce the SQL from the log, then `$1=$1` is fine. Otherwise, you'll want to trim with `sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Howabout a combination of `sed` and `tr`

```
sed 's/^[0-9][^S]*//' INPUT.txt | sed '/^[0-9a-z]/d' | tr -s ' ' | tr -d '\n'
```

output:

```
STATEMENT: SELECT count(*) AS total FROM ( SELECT 1 AS count FROM leads_search_criteria_entities INNER JOIN entities e on entity_id = e.viq_id LEFT JOIN companies_user cu ON cu.entity_id = e.viq_id WHERE criterium_id = 644 AND (( ( cu.udef_type IS NULL -- if not set by user, check calculated value AND is_university >= 50 ) OR ( cu.udef_type IS NOT NULL -- if set by user, use it AND cu.udef_type = 'university' ) )) GROUP BY e.viq_id ORDER BY e.viq_id ) x
```

Comment: This misses the end of the first line 'SELECT count (*) ...'

Comment: Crap, didn't see that line. I'll through in a sed to include that one as well, give me a sec... Thanks for pointing out my misstake!

Comment: 'misstake' has only one 's'.   ;-)